# Touch move event not correct

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, socket.io, touch

I'm busy creating a small real time drawing app and got stuck trying to create a touchscreen system. It's partially working but when I touch and move the line connects to the last line.

Here's my code:

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 var mouse = { 
  click: false,
  move: false,
  pos: {x:0, y:0},
  pos_prev: false,
  colour: "blue"

};

var canvas  = document.getElementById('drawing');

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var width   = window.innerWidth;
var height  = window.innerHeight;
var socket  = io.connect();

  canvas.width = width;
 canvas.height = height;

 /* window.onresize= function(){ 
 var width   = window.innerWidth;
  var height  = window.innerHeight;
  console.log(height);
  canvas.style.width = width;
  canvas.style.height = height;
     }; */

   canvas.onmousedown = function(e){ mouse.click = true; };
    canvas.onmouseup = function(e){ mouse.click = false; };
   canvas.ontouchstart = function(e){ mouse.click = true; };
   canvas.ontouchend = function(e){ mouse.click = false; };

   canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {

  mouse.pos.x = e.clientX / width;
  mouse.pos.y = e.clientY / height;
  mouse.pos.w = document.getElementById("rag").value;
  mouse.move = true;
    };
    canvas.ontouchmove = function(e) { 
  var touch = e.touches[0];
  var x = touch.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  var y = touch.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
  mouse.pos.x = x / width;
  mouse.pos.y = y / height;
  console.log(mouse.pos.x);
  mouse.pos.w = document.getElementById("rag").value;
  mouse.move = true; 
  };


   socket.on('draw_line', function (data) {
  var line = data.line;

  ctx.strokeStyle = line[2];
  ctx.lineWidth = line[0].w;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(line[0].x * width, line[0].y * height);
  ctx.lineTo(line[1].x * width, line[1].y * height);
  ctx.stroke();

    });
   socket.on('clear', function () {
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);

     });

      function mainLoop() {

   if (mouse.click && mouse.move && mouse.pos_prev) {

      mouse.colour = document.getElementById("col").value;
       socket.emit('draw_line', { line: [ mouse.pos, mouse.pos_prev,      mouse.colour]});
     mouse.move = false;
   }
     mouse.pos_prev = {x: mouse.pos.x, y: mouse.pos.y};
     setTimeout(mainLoop, 20);
      }
       mainLoop();
      });
```

A life example can be found here:

http://80.61.54.121:88/

Does anyone know how to fix the lines connecting with eacother? Thanks in advance.